# Integrate AWS Lex to website(lambda implemented in python runtime)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

Im working on a bot and would like to integrate to a website for my project. My Bot is fully functional, lambda fulfillment coded in python runtime. I see [example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui) of how to integrate bot implemented in javascript(lambda node runtime) but not able to find help for python implementation.

Does my bot need to be implemented in  javascript(lambda node runtime)  to be able to integrate with website?

I not very familiar with UI stuff and any help to get me started is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bot can be written in any language and still be integrated with a website.

You can use an AWS SDK to access the bot or `HTTPS` calls.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html) for `HTTPS` calls:

```
POST /bot/botName/alias/botAlias/user/userId/text HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json

{
   "inputText": "string",
   "requestAttributes": { 
      "string" : "string" 
   },
   "sessionAttributes": { 
      "string" : "string" 
   }
}
```

Or you can use an SDK. This can be done through the UI layer, using the [JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html); or through the website back-end, using the SDK that matches your backend. Here's the [list of SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/).

You will be calling [these methods from the Lex SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_Operations_Amazon_Lex_Runtime_Service.html) to use your bot. `PostContent` is for sending voice, and `PostText` is for sending text. The `response` will contain the bots response.

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for your response. I will try and update here